# How can I expand a spreadsheet formula so that one number increases with the row, but the other is static?

Tags: google-sheets

This is a basic spreadsheet question, so thank you for your patience.

Suppose I have a column of data. To the right of each cell in that column, I'd like to display the value in that column minus the value in another cell-- let's say the column is B2:B5 and the static cell is A1. If I type in

```
=(B2-A1)
```

I get the correct output, of course. But if I drag this formula to the rest of the column, the desired output is

```
=(B3-A1)
=(B4-A1)
=(B5-A1)
```

But the actual output is

```
=(B3-A2)
=(B4-A3)
=(B5-A4)
```

Believing in the power of Google's near-sentient powers, I figured if I just helped it by starting with

```
=(B2-A1)
=(B3-A1)
=(B4-A1)
```

Then it would recognize the pattern and stop incrementing the second cell. Sadly, the same result occurs.

I suppose I could write a Google-Apps-Script formula for this, or a Macro in Excel, but I'm wondering-- is there a simpler trick for it? Can I teach it which letters to expand and which to leave alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of A1, try $A$1. The $ sign locks down the row or column, and in this case, both.